# Padding in Firefox 1px short or IE 1px over

Tags: html, css, image

I am having a problem with the below html code when using an image the different is 1px; to short in Firefox, it is ok in IE9, Chrome Opera, it just Firefox.

I have tried removing the image and it all lines up ok.
See under code for screenshots of IE and Firefox:

Here is the html code:

XXX

```
        <div style="background:url(images/package_bg.gif) repeat-x; border-color: #ccc; float: left; width: 20px; padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 2px; padding-left: 5px; border-style: solid; border-right-color: #FFFFFF; border-width: 1px;"><img src="images/info.png" onmouseover="site.showTooltip(this,'xxx');" onmouseout="site.hideTooltip('xxx');"></div>
        <div style="background:url(images/package_bg.gif) repeat-x; border-color: #ccc; float: left; width: 173px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px; border-style: solid; border-right-color: #FFFFFF; border-width: 1px; text-align: center;">xxx</div>
        <div style="background:url(images/package_bg.gif) repeat-x; border-color: #ccc; float: left; width: 173px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px; border-style: solid; border-right-color: #FFFFFF; border-width: 1px; text-align: center;">xxx</div>
        <div style="background:url(images/package_bg.gif) repeat-x; border-color: #ccc; float: left; width: 173px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px; border-top-right-radius: 10px; border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; text-align: center;">xxx</div>
        <div style="clear: both; padding-bottom: 0px;"> </div>
```

Firefox: http://www.cbg.me.uk/html/firefox.jpg

IE: http://www.cbg.me.uk/html/ie.jpg

I am not sure how to fix this, as if I add the 1px Firefox is ok, but IE, Chrome and Opera is 1px over.

Thanks

Comment: to start off, I would take all the styles out from inline, and add them to a stylesheet. Once you do that. Create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with a fullpath to the image so we can see it.

Comment: I will be before going live with the site, I just find it easier to put them in the page and move them into a style sheet once that page is done

Comment: Thats more than doubling the amount of work for you. For now could you give us the fullpath to the image so we can see it?

Comment: I would also like to see your complete code in order to figure out the doctype implied, the quirkMode trigger, etc etc.

In the meanwhile, you can try the div{ box-sizing: border-box }

Comment: I have found the problem it down to the font-size set in the stylesheet of font-size: 13px;. So I have added font-size: 6px; to that row and it looks good in ie and firefox now, need to test other browsers

Comment: Just change the row to font-size: 1px; add a 1px on the padding-bottom and testing in IE 6/8/9 and Firefox, Chrome and Opera and it looks fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a browser difference of the border.  Put your css in a style sheet and add this to the offending blocks:

```
If you want show like FF: 
border-collapse:collapse

If you want show like IE (not 100% on this one):
border-collapse:separate
```

Comment: Will give this a try, when I put that page into the style sheet.

Comment: Problem came back, so tried this it didn't work in the div. When I did was CSS it all including the image calls from the style sheet.

Comment: Do you know exactly where the 1px is coming from?  Is it on the div or the image?  I would look at the IE developer tools (f12).  This is actually really good for helping you see all the little IE bugs.  IE and Firefox add borders differently, with IE adding the border on the outside (resulting in additional width) and FF adding it on the inside.  Once you nail down where it is coming through, it should be easy to fix it.

Comment: It was coming from the image, as without the image it was fine, it all browsers. I also added: vertical-align: bottom;

Answer (score 1):

Changed the row with the image to font-size: 1px; and added 1px; to the padding-bottom.

Have tested in IE 6/8/9, Firefox (latest), Chrome (latest) and Opera (latest) and it is all lined up.

Comment: This problem came back, so what I did in the end, put the CSS in the style sheet and then create background-images in css, to put them where they need to be. All lines up now, just need to make 1 new button.

Answer (score 1):

Please, use this hack. Inside Your CSS put something like this:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .selector {
     padding-bottom: XX px;
  }
}
```

Where is selector - Write Your class / id where You see the difference.
There You can set Your new padding just for FireFox.